# SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException GAE + PrimeFaces + Spring + Maven ,BookList application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, primefaces

While running GAE + PrimeFaces + Spring + Maven ,BookList application, 
    got some errors on saving book title and author in to Datastore using JDO.
    like,

```
**Oct 25, 2011 11:10:24 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'java.lang.NullPointerException' when invoking action listener '#                   {createBook.save}' for component 'j_idt11'
Oct 25, 2011 11:10:24 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException**

error with the highlighted line.Please give a solution.  

public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
System.out.println("in actionEvent");

**bookDAO.persist(book);** //getting values here correctly.But cannot save!
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Book is saved");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
book = new MyBook();
}

thanks.
```

Comment: No JDO present in the post, so don't see its relevance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That suggests that `bookDAO` is probably null. That's the first thing to check... how are you setting the `bookDAO` field?